# mapping loads of XSDs to DB

Tags: xml, database, oracle, xsd, mapping

I have a task to create converter from xml to db (Oracle 11).

I have many (about 100) xsds provided by customer. Each xsd describes really complex data. Some xsds have common types but each xsd declares all types inside, so there is no xsd with common types.

DB model is not provided. But client rejected variant based on using oracle xmldb.

My plan was:

1. generate db model using xmlspy;
2. generate java model using jaxb;
3. map java to db model using hibernate;
4. read xml data using jaxb to java model;
5. store data using hibernate.

But when I tried to generate db module, I saw that xmlspy produced more than 5000 tables. Even I can reduce the count of them, there is still too much work to verify and fix generated relations between tables. Also there is a lot of work to generate java model and map it to the db.

Are there any other alternatives to solve my issue?

Comment: Why there are 100 schemas? Are these functionally related? Why are you storing the data in DB? How is will the data be used after storing in DB?

Comment: Schemas describe different kinds of financial reports. Data form xml will be provided to BI system. Storing data in the DB is customer
requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an impossible task without analysing the XML data and then mapping this to a relational data model in your database.

The approach you've outlined is a fairly mechanical process that demonstrates how it's difficult to automate this process... Each XSD type in your XSD generated a unique object class in Java, which in turn was converted into a unique table in your database by Hibernate...

If your schemas use type inheritance, this might give you some clues into the relational data structure (XSD types inheriting a common parent type, might belong in the same table). Perhaps others can offer other common patterns to watch out for.

## Update

I suggest a closer look at the underlying XML data.

I remember a previous web services project where we completely re-wrote the customer's schema, based on the raw XML data we received. It emerged that their complex XSD types were completely superflous and just added complexity.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I agree with you that there are a lot of routine work, so I`m interested in finding more effective mapping approach. As I say schemas were provided by customer, so I can`t change them. Also I`ve analyzed this schemas, and it is possible to reduce the count of them (5-10 times), but there are still much routine work to do.

Comment: @2dy I'm afraid this "routine" work cannot be avoided. XML data modelling and relational data modelling are too dissimilar. That was why I suggested looking at the underlying data and concentrate on loading it into a sensible DB schema. Otherwise confusion would continue when the customer attempts to analyse data using SQL.

Comment: Thank you for ansver. I`m afraid you a right. It seems that there is no other way, only data anlyze.